# ios sent image to mail client from app is not displayed

Tags: ios, image, file

I would like to open native mail client on my application and send the following:

```
NSString *subject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.selectedProposal.title];

NSString *mail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];

NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation( self.logoImageView.image )];
CreditCalculatorModel *model = [CreditCalculatorModel tlSharedInstance];
NSString *emailBody = @"";
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p><center><img src='data:image/png;base64,%@'></center></p>", [imageData base64EncodedString]]];
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingFormat:@"<p><center><h4>%@</h4></center></p>", self.selectedProposal.title];
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingString:@"<br />"];
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingString:self.amountLabel.text];
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingString:@"<br />"];
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingString:self.initialLabel.text];
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingString:@"<br />"];
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingString:self.creditAmountLabel.text];
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingString:@"<br />"];
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingFormat:@"Процентная ставка: %@", self.rateLabel.text];
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingString:@"<br />"];
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingFormat:@"Эффективная ставка: %@", self.efficientRateLabel.text];
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingString:@"<br />"];
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingFormat:@"Ежемесячный платёж: %@", self.paymentLabel.text];
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingString:@"<br />"];
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingFormat:@"Переплата по кредиту: %@", self.overheadLabel.text];
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingString:@"<br />"];
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingString:@"<br /></h5>График платежей</h5><br />"];
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingString:@"<table border='1'>"];
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingString:@"<tr><td>Месяц</td><td>Задолженность</td><td>Платёж</td></tr>"];
for ( int i = 0; i < model.term; i++ )
{
    emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingFormat:@"<tr><td>%d</td><td>%@ р.</td><td>%@ р.</td></tr>",
                 i + 1,
                 [self.unicomDecimalNumberFormatter stringFromNumber:@((int) [CreditCalculatorModel deptForMonth:i
                                                                                                        withRate:[self.selectedProposal.rate doubleValue]/100
                                                                                                       andAmount:model.amount
                                                                                                         andTerm:model.term
                                                                                                      andInitial:model.initial
                                                                                                      andAnnuity:!self.selectedProposal.payment_type])],
                 [self.unicomDecimalNumberFormatter stringFromNumber:@((int) [CreditCalculatorModel paymentForMonth:i
                                                                                                           withRate:[self.selectedProposal.rate doubleValue]/100
                                                                                                          andAmount:model.amount
                                                                                                            andTerm:model.term
                                                                                                         andInitial:model.initial
                                                                                                         andAnnuity:!self.selectedProposal.payment_type])]
                 ];
}
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingString:@"</table>"];






NSString *recipients = @"mailto:?to=";

NSString *subjectMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&subject=%@", subject];

NSString *bodyMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&body=%@", emailBody];

NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", recipients, subjectMessage, bodyMessage];

email = [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:email]];
```

Everything is OK, beside image representation. It is not displayed. On the place of image appear only a little empty rectangle. 
Image representation is ON in phone options.
And I can't do this task with MFMailComposeViewController.
Thx for helping

Comment: why do you think the mobile Safari browser is going to *automatically decode* your Base64Encoded image when displaying your e-mail message?

Comment: Why can't you use `MFMailComposeViewController`?

Comment: I can't use MFMailComposeController, because I init this action on right SideBar controller, and obviously there are a lot of problems with sizes.

Comment: Michael Dautermann, basically, as I know, native mail and safari use Base64Encoded images for representation. Actually, I can open link of my image in Safari and everything all right.

Comment: Is `imageData`=`nil` or `[imageData base64EncodedString]`=`nil`by any chance?

Comment: Amar, obviously not. I checked it in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

try this method :

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailer setSubject:@"Message"];
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fisrtMail@example.com", @"secondMail@example.com", nil];
    [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
    [mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"mobiletutsImage"];
    NSString *emailBody = @"your email body";
    [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];
    [mailer release];
```

Comment: As I said before I could use  MFMailComposeViewController. I just need to send my image to mail client. Nevertheless, thx for advice!